VBA in Excel - User-defined type not defined error
I am getting this error message popping up in a workbook I have, but not when I am running the macro (there's only one in the workbook at the moment).  The macro runs fine with no errors, but any time I enter any data into a cell in any worksheet I get this pop up error message.
I've looked in tools/references and everything looks ok there, I have stripped out the raw data and put it in a brand new workbook and then as soon as I re-introduce the macro code, the error returns.  Here's the code in question, I have gone through it multiple times and can't see any issues and as I say it runs fine and does what I want it to do.
Sub ImportEOD()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Dim rd As Worksheet
Set rd = wb.Sheets("RawData")
Dim rdlr As Long
If IsEmpty(rd.Range("A2")) Then
rdlr = 3
Else: rdlr = rd.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
End If

Dim nwb As Workbook
Set nwb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="S:\Hard Wired Measures.....DO NOT DELETE\Data Extracts\Power BI\EOD new data.xlsx")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = nwb.Sheets(1)
Dim lr As Long
lr = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

ws.Range("A1:BK" & lr).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("O1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Dim err As Integer
err = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("O2:O" & lr), "<1")

If err > 0 Then
    Dim rngend As Integer
    rngend = err + 1
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("O2:O" & rngend)
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value < 1 Then
        cell.Offset(0, -4).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next cell
End If

ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & lr).Replace What:=" Callout Only", Replacement:="", MatchCase:=False
ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & lr).Replace What:="Tanker Rate - ", Replacement:=""
ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & lr).Replace What:="QUOTED ", Replacement:=""
ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & lr).Replace What:="~*", Replacement:=""
ws.Range("AJ2:AJ" & lr).Replace "`", "'"
ws.Range("A1:BJ" & lr).Replace What:=" Quoted Works Only", Replacement:=""

Dim dt As Date
Dim dt2 As Date
Dim dt3 As Date
dt = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range("P2:P" & lr)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
dt2 = Format(DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) + 1, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
dt3 = Format(DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) + 2, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")

wb.Activate
rd.AutoFilterMode = False

rd.Range("A1:BJ" & rdlr).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Array(Format(dt, "mmm-yy"), Format(dt2, "mmm-yy"), Format(dt3, "mmm-yy")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
rd.Range("A1:BJ" & rdlr).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Clear
rd.AutoFilterMode = False
rd.Range("A1:BJ" & rdlr).Sort Key1:=rd.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
rdlr = rd.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

nwb.Activate
ws.Range("A2:BJ" & lr).Copy Destination:=rd.Range("A" & rdlr)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
nwb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub




Is there any code in the ThisWorkbook module?

No, just in a module I inserted manually

Do you have any add-ins loaded?

No, no add-ins at all

What if you copy-paste the code into an empty module in a new workbook (rather than inserting the module)? It almost sounds like you have a file which has become corrupted.

I've tried that, I copy-pasted the code into notepad, and from there into a brand new workbook and module.

The issue looks to be related to the 3 Date variables.  "Date" is a valid datatype, but the fact that it isn't in black text, but rather in red/orange text tells me that it's being treated as a constant.  Which is really odd...  Which References do you have selected?

I've got 4 references: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, and Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

Shouldn't use err As Intger, as that shadows the Err object. I suspect that won't fix the issue tho.

Is there a "Debug" button in the error pop-up?  If No then try setting your VBA error handling to "Break in class module" and see if that changes anything.

There's no debug button, and there's no error in the actual code.  I tried changing the error handling and nothing has changed.
